# The following error occurred while fetching values for input 'Artifacts': The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: tfs, ms-release-management

I'm having some trouble linking an internal Git repository to a Release Definition in TFS 2017. Other internal Git repositories doesn't show me the same message.

Any ideas?

[Message when linking Git repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5B747.png)

Comment: Did you double check if you have enough permission to access that special repo?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT, thanks for the reply. I guess it is something to do with the permissions, I thought I was admin on everything, but not for this Team Project. Now I'm waiting for the other admin to give me the permissions I need. I'll get back when I get a response.

Comment: Hi Bruno,  any update on this issue, did you figure out it?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT, It was permission. As soon as I was granted, I could link the repo. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you have enough **permission to access** that special repo.

---

If you already have the appropriate permissions but the issue still exists. There maybe something broke the repository mapping. Try below method with the similar issue.

> In the TFS_Collection database there is a tbl_AccessMapping table. 
>   That table was empty, no entries.  I copied the data from the row in
>   the same table in the TFS_Configuration database that has the
>   PublicAccessMapping moniker.  All worked after this entry was created
>   in the TFS_Collection:tbl_AccessMapping table.
>
> *Source Link:* [TFS 2010 - Error "Given key was not present in the dictionary" when opening a connection](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fa4914d8-135e-4278-9b69-1c9ac71fa1d7/tfs-2010-error-given-key-was-not-present-in-the-dictionary-when-opening-a-connection?forum=tfsadmin)